# How does the prefix ad- explain the differences between apparaître vs. paraître?

Tags: différence

On March 5 2008, [Jeanbar](https://forum.wordreference.com/members/jeanbar.201744/) [wrote](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/para%C3%AEtre-appara%C3%AEtre.162652/post-4598041)

> Your initial question was the distinction between apparaître/paraître.
>
> - apparaitre: to appear suddenly or by surprise,
> - paraitre: to come out but not unexpectedly,
>
> the difference lies in the prefix ad- which reinforces the verb, hence the surprise.

Neither [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/appara%C3%AEtre) or [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/appara%C3%AEtre#%C3%89tymologie) write outright that *apparaître* = *ad-* + *paraître*. But I see that [*appareo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/appareo#Etymology) = [[*ad-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ad-#Latin) (“towards”) +‎ [*pāreō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pareo#Latin) (“be visible”).

##### But kindly expatiate Jeanbar's one sentence? French learners like me need more detail! How does *ad-* beget the [différence[s?] entre *paraître* et *apparaître*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/index.php?id=23852)?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: We can read in [Le préfixe a- 1 ad- en moyen français](https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_2001_num_119_475_1560): « Certaines formations latines [...] sont passées en français sans demeurer analysables. On les considèrera, en moyen français, comme des « dérivés historiques » et non comme des dérivés authentiques [...] Ces verbes ne sont guère analysables qu'à travers le latin. ».   *Apparaitre* is listed among these verbs, so the question might be better on [Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/). As far as what s.o. meant on WR, why not ask them there?

Comment: @None Voulez-vous poser cette question en latin SE, puisque c'est (je l'admets) votre idée sagace ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation for this morphology is given in the TLFi precisely for the verb "apparaitre". In the end it is what the French language made of what it borrowed from another language that counts for determining the signification attached to a form.

The so-called reinforcement is but a personal  apprehension of the idea and one should take it with scare quotes. The following analysis is however something to ponder seriously. (There is in this entry much additional information on the **a-** prefix ("élément formant", that is, in English, "combining form" ), and it is sufficient for any student of the morphology of words containing "a-".)

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a-))  **a-** Exprime une idée de passage d'un état à un autre, ou d'attrib., ou de direction vers un lieu, ou de manière ou encore d'inchoativité.
> **III.** − Dans les dérivés de verbes : idée d'inchoativité de l'action
> **C.** −
> **apparaître.** − Le verbe *paraître* signifie « se montrer » (aux yeux). L'apparition est le début de cette action, l'instant seulement où la chose se révèle (au sens propre et au sens figuré) : un personnage apparaît sur la scène (sens propre) ; dans un roman un personnage nous apparaît honnête, bon, etc. (sens fig.)